# Manually specify library when pyinstaller sees conflicting versions

Tags: macos, pyinstaller

Is it possible to manually replace or specify the location of a .dylib on Mac OSX when using pyinstaller?

I'm getting the error when trying to open my completed .app

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "DeepMeerkat/main.py", line 3, in <module>
    import cv2
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 546, in load_module
    module = imp.load_module(fullname, fp, filename, ext_tuple)
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/ben/Documents/DeepMeerkat/Installer/dist/Lib/cv2.so, 2): Library not loaded: @loader_path/libpng16.16.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/ben/Documents/DeepMeerkat/Installer/dist/Lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.3.3.dylib
  Reason: Incompatible library version: libopencv_imgcodecs.3.3.dylib requires version 48.0.0 or later, but libpng16.16.dylib provides version 45.0.0
Failed to execute script main
```

I have no problem loading cv2 in python outside of the app, or any other problems with open, which was installed with homebrew.

Poking around, I think it is extremely likely the error comes from pyinstaller grabbing libpng from X11 (`/opt/X11/include/libpng16`) when it needs to be grabbing from Homebrew's folders (`/usr/local/Cellar/libpng/1.6.32/`)

How can I use a hook to specify which libpng I want?

Comment: manually replacing the file worked, but won't scale well. I'll keep this open.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem,  the answer lay in editing the .spec file. Add the following line after a = Analysis...:

```
a.binaries = a.binaries - TOC([('libpng16.16.dylib',None,None)])
```

This has the effect of removing the offending dylib from the relevant TOC file which solves the conflict.

Comment: This fix works and is (unfortunately) still relevant with Python 3.7, pyinstaller 3.5, while running on macos 10.14.6

Comment: Yes, Python 3.7, pyinstaller version 3.6 here. This worked.