# How to fix ImportError with pyinstaller?

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I'm trying to make standalone app with pyinstaller.

And following is the error when I tried to execute the application.

```
ImportError: dlopen(/var/folders/sd/zq4jyps57_13mpn3ftzr_y_c0000gn/T/_MEIp7CX4r/cv2/cv2.cpython-37m-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: @loader_path/libpng16.16.dylib
  Referenced from: /private/var/folders/sd/zq4jyps57_13mpn3ftzr_y_c0000gn/T/_MEIp7CX4r/libfreetype.6.dylib
  Reason: Incompatible library version: libfreetype.6.dylib requires version 54.0.0 or later, but libpng16.16.dylib provides version 38.0.0
```

Please help me with this problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Manually specify library when pyinstaller sees conflicting versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46246649/manually-specify-library-when-pyinstaller-sees-conflicting-versions)

Comment: Could you please mention the OS, distribution, and show the code snippet? It will be useful in diagnosing your problem.